# Como habilitar HTTP Keep Alive

Tags: php, apache, http

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que precisa realizar muitas requisições ao back-end. Gostaria de experimentar o modelo de manter a conexão aberta: *keep-alive*.

Mas na pratica não tenho ideia por onde começar: apache? serviço php?

Já vi que o axios envia *http header*, mas não exatamente se a conexão é mantida aberta...

Comment: Você já tem o backend feito ?

Comment: Sim, backend já implementado, quero ver se consigo otimizar com keep alive agora.

Answer (score -1):

O PHP não foi feito para manter a conexão ativa, mesmo que seja possível, acho que seria mais fácil com o NodeJS. Mas você pode configurar o Apache assim:

**httpd.conf**

```
KeepAlive: on/off         # :)
MaxKeepAliveRequests: 50  #acho que aqui é mais que suficiente
KeepAliveTimeout: 5       #vá testando, mas creio que esse valor seja ideal
MaxClients: 75            #75 por 1GB, se tem 2GB de RAM, 150
ServerLimit: 75           #Mesmo número do MaxClients
MaxConnectionsPerChild: 2 #Importante, só não deixa o valor 0 "infinito", que é padrão
MaxRequestsPerChild: 2    #mesma função do MaxConnectionsPerChild, veja descrição
```

Descrição

```
KeepAlive: Liga ou desliga.

MaxKeepAliveRequests: Número máximo de requisições que uma conexão poderá efetuar.

KeepAliveTimeout: Quanto tempo a conexão vai esperar por uma nova requisição de um cliente já conectado.

MaxClients: Quantidade de processos filhos do apache

ServerLimit: Use este ao invés de MaxClients se estiver usando prefork MPM, caso não, use ServerLimit e MaxClients no mesmo valor.

MaxConnectionsPerChild: Quantidade máxima de de conexões por uma processo filho, o padrão é 0 "ilimitado", tente colocar um valor que não seja zero, mas que não seja muito alto, isto é algo que você terá que fazer os cálculos para não acabar com a memória

MaxRequestsPerChild: é o mesmo caso do MaxConnectionsPerChild, só use esta opção se estiver usando Apache < 2.3.9. Apache >= 2.3.9 use o MaxConnectionsPerChild
```

Tome cuidado com a maioria das opções aqui citadas, podem comer memória do servidor se não configuradas corretamente, algumas você terá que fazer cálculos em relação a memória e CPU disponível.

Se estiver usando o Nginx, procure na documentação e tente seguir a mesma lógica

---

Fontes:

https://abdussamad.com/archives/535-Apache-MaxClients.html
https://abdussamad.com/archives/169-Apache-optimization:-KeepAlive-On-or-Off.html
https://serverfault.com/a/28311
https://serverfault.com/a/713098
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#maxconnectionsperchild